# How to get All active span links in textView android

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, talkback

I have a textview that has a text inside with some links (some of them are custom for example bank card number which I manually made them linkable), is there a way that I extract all linked part of textview in a list?

I want this for handle links via TalkBack

Example:

> This is text for **www.google.com** with number **6273 5331 2134 1234**

I want to get these bold texts:

- www.google.com
- 6273 5331 2134 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Found the answer:

Just convert the text to **Editable** then retrieve all of your spans.

```
Editable editable = new Editable.Factory().newEditable(textView.getText());

ClickableSpan[] ClickableSpans = editable.getSpans(0,editable.length(), ClickableSpan.class);
ClickableSpan[] UrlSpans = editable.getSpans(0,editable.length(), URLSpan.class);
```

You can retrieve all CustomSpans from the above method.
This also works for editText too.

Comment: Yes this works but easier would be to cast it to Spanned

`(textView.text as? Spanned).getSpans(....)`